# Убрать системное меню навигации

Tags: android, java, qt, c++

Есть приложение на QT C++ для Android. Стоит задача развернуть приложение на весь экран. Задача частично решена, на весь экран сделал, но там появляется всплывающая подсказка: "Для выхода из полноэкранного режима проведите пальцем вниз". Хотелось бы эту подсказку тоже отключить, кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста. Теперь надо запретить пользователю приложение закрывать. Требуется:

1. Убрать системное меню навигации android (назад, выход в главное меню и т.п.) программным способом или командой через adb. И предусмотреть также возврат этого меню. Технически если есть реализация вызова команды в консоль через QT, вариант подойдет. Если есть вариант на JAVA, тоже пишите.
2. Отключить или переопределить боковые кнопки громкости. Также любым способом.

Comment: а что будете делать с аппаратными кнопками "назад" "домой"? изолентой закрывать?

Боковые кнопки громкости переопределяются легко.

Рекомендую просто сделать свое приложение "лаунчером".

Comment: RE: а что будете делать с аппаратными кнопками "назад" "домой"? изолентой закрывать?
Это и есть поставленная задача
RE: Боковые кнопки громкости переопределяются легко.
Как? Стандартными настройками Android можно сделать?
RE: Рекомендую просто сделать свое приложение "лаунчером".
Что такое лаунчер? Пример реализации.